# png image transition on click with stable background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I am unable to make it, I have used several things and I have wasted almost 2 days making this thing but still not get what my client wants

after seeing the image you might get the idea what I am looking for, I am trying to move the png image on click, what will happen is the png image on which a user click will take the place of previous png on front and the background will remain stable.

This is the link to the image:
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=9hj90h&s=8#.U1Shkld4Pcc

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this jQuery plugin http://3.s3.envato.com/files/37836635/index2.html

Answer (score 0):

are you searching for a [carousel jquery plugin](https://www.google.ch/search?q=carousel%20plugin%20jquery) or are you trying to implement this yourself?

If you really want us to help, please provide a jsfiddle. I can only make assumptions and give some general advice; the background image should be a separate image from the images you want to translate (and make a transition). Each image needs its own click event (or an observer on the document). When the user clicks, find out which location the current image is at. Find the image the current image should be at. Get the location. Change the top/left style values of the image.

Of course, you will need a `[browser-prefix]-transition: all 2s linear` on each element that should transition

Answer (score 0):

what i understand is that you want to basically set new css values to the image(-holder).

$('#yourelementid').animate(height= new_height, width=new_width, otherattr=new_attr)

if you already know the values you need it should be quite straight forward.

here is the man page for $.animate()
https://api.jquery.com/animate/

hint: in the site that you give as reference he uses a separate image to display on click rather to move the existing one to the center.

You can have an invisible element with absolute position on the center, and on click fill it with the selected image, and make it visible.

hope this helps